# Infinitive used as imperative

Tags: грамматика, повелительное-наклонение

Are the imperative and infinitive always completely reasonable alternatives?

E.g.:

> Сидеть!  -  сиди!
>
> не повторя́ть! -  не повторя́й!

Comment: see [link] (http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/imperatives-and-aspect?rq=1) Imperatives and Aspect

Comment: _‘Не повторя́ть!>’_ not _‘Не повтори́ть!’_

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov is "повторять" the imperfective? as "повторяй" is?

Comment: Yes, exactly. _Повторя́й_ is a singular imperative form of _повторя́ть_. The same form of _повтори́ть_ would be _повтори́_.

Comment: The linked question contains a thorough explanation. My examples are from a movie where the guard is instructing a prisoner (фартовый)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight difference between them, the infinite sentences used as imperative are much more aggressive and exigent. For example, only infinite sentences are used to train dogs:

Ша́рик, сиде́ть! 
Sharik (dog's name), sit!

Ты посиди́ здесь, а я пойду́ посмотрю́, в чём там де́ло.
Stay (sit) here, and I will see what is happening.

Comment: I get the example in regards to the question, but I dont understand "я пойду́ посмотрю́." Is "посмотрю́" the direct object of "пойду́" (like "I will have a _look_")? Or are they both verbs that agree with "я?"

Comment: In this case it is not the imperative or the infinite construction. It is a colloquial expression, used normally with the verbs of movement. These are two verbs in the form of the 1st person, singular (я):

Я пойду посмотрю (colloquial speech) = Я пойду посмотреть (neurtral speech)
Я сбегаю куплю хлеб (colloquial speech) = Я сбегаю купить хлеб (neutral speech).

Comment: Can you use it any person? eg Ты посиди́ здесь, а _он пойдёт посмо́трит_, в чём там де́ло.

Comment: Yes, you can use it in any person.